# Partially publishing flutter flavors

Tags: android, ios, flutter, publish

As far as I know flutter flavors are used to create apps with same codebase but different assets and styles in general.

However, I created a flutter flavor that follows another page path, to make it more clear different login page, different home page and etc. There are 2 different page paths, each is followed by one specific flavor.

As you can imagine, I merged 2 apps in a single project using flavors. Because of that, the size of the app is doubled. Imagine publishing the each flavor as different apps on the app store or play store, I want to make sure that I do not publish the entire project for each flavor even though flavors do not use both page paths.

Is there a way to partially publish, or publish only the neccessary files only for each flavor? Does anyone have any clue about a solution to the mentioned problem?

I published one of the flavors already but I am not sure if the flavor contains all the files or only the required ones for the flavor.